# Conditional Validation in a FieldArray using Formik & Yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I have a ScheduleForm that has nested values called `hours_attributes`. The individual hours have a binding conditional where the presence of the `opens` value is required if the `all_day` value is false. Here's how my current schema is written:

```
const ScheduleSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string()
    .required('Required'),
  hours_attributes: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
      opens: Yup.object().when('all_day', {
      is: false,
      then: Yup.string().required('Required'),
      otherwise: Yup.string()
    }),
  }))
});
```

I'm not sure if the `when` value is expecting the index of that particular hour's `all_day` value. Do I need some sort of index?

Answer (score 1):

Try by giving a function to 2nd argument of `when`:

```
const ScheduleSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string()
    .required('Required'),
  hours_attributes: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
      opens: Yup.boolean().when('all_day', (value, schema) =>
        value ? schema : schema.required('Required')),
  }))
});
```

If above snippet doesn’t work then change `hours_attributes` like:

```
Yup.object({
      opens: Yup.boolean().when('all_day', (value, schema) =>
        value ? schema : schema.required('Required'))
}),
```

If you want value of `opens` to be true then:

```
Yup.object({
      opens: Yup.boolean().when('all_day', (value, schema) =>
        value ? schema : schema.oneOf([true], 'Required'))
}),
```

Comment: What is the type of open?

Comment: It's a boolean.

Comment: Does it mean that when `all_day` is false then `opens` should be true? If yes then you should try like:
```js

Yup.object({
      opens: Yup.boolean().when('all_day', (value, schema) =>
        value ? schema : schema.oneOf([true], 'Opens should be true'))
}),
```